# Maintain the State of Onchange After Error Is Thrown

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, hide, show

When a specific value is chosen from a drop-down menu, a div's "show" or "hide" property is set using the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id_record_filter_key").change(function() {
            // advanced-search is the id of the div containing the additional search fields
            if ($(this).val() != 0) {
                $("#advanced-search").show();
            } else {
                $("#advanced-search").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But if the page yields a data validation error, the "show/hide" value of this property of the div is not retained. How can this be retained when an error is thrown?

Comment: How are you doing the validation?

Comment: Django is doing the validation. Data validation constraints are defined in a Django form class.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Is the validation of the Django form ran during form submission or are you doing validation on each field in the form as you leave the form, say by pressing the TAB key or something?

Comment: The validation is done when the form is submitted. It's simple Django based form validation that only checks for required fields. When the div is on "show" and a required validation error is thrown, when the page returns the div is set back to "hide".

Comment: So I believe the problem then is when you are submitting with Django there is a callback either to the same page (meaning there is a reload of the page you are currently on), or to a new page.  In your case, the validation is failing and reloading the page so it's going back to its original state, nothing is selected.  If you wanted to keep your state, the best chance I believe you have is pass in the value of the selected drop-down to the validation call and upon failing, pass it back to the page reload call.  I'm not sure if that will solve the problem but I can't think of any other way.

Comment: Solved this issue by using HTML 5 for "required" validation instead of Django. Thanks for your suggestions.